# Поиск и добавление элементов из Map в List (Java Stream API)

Tags: java, list, map, java-8, java-stream

У меня есть `Map<String, Item>`, где Item — это сущности, которые мне нужно собрать в отдельный `List<Item>`. Собрать нужные Item я пытаюсь в методе `formOrders`:

```
public class InvoiceData {
    static final Vendor vendor = Vendor.getInstance();

    private List<Invoice> orders;
    private List<Customer> customers;
    private Map<String, Item> items;

    public List<Invoice> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }

    public InvoiceData() {
        orders = formOrders();
    }

    //...сustomerSupplier, itemSupplier...

    public List<Invoice> formOrders() {
        // Список заказов. Сюда, собственно, будут собираться объекты Invoice.
        List<Invoice> result = new ArrayList<>();

        customers = customerSupplier.get(); // Покупатели
        items = itemSupplier.get(); // Товары

        customers.forEach(customer -> {
            Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
            result.add(invoice);

            invoice.setVendor(vendor);
            invoice.setRecipient(customer);
            invoice.setTax(0.2);

            invoice.setItems(items.entrySet().stream()
                    .filter(item -> item.getKey().equals(customer.getId()))
                    .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));

        });

        return result;
    }
}
```

Сам список заказов `orders` состоит из объектов класса `Invoice`:

```
public class Invoice {
    private Vendor vendor;
    private Customer recipient;
    private List<Item> items;
    private BigDecimal priceOverall;
    private Double tax;

    public Invoice() {
    }

    // ...get и set...
}
```

В классе `InvoiceData` происходит "наполнение" данными. В дальнейшем объект этого класса будет использован для генерации отчётов (dynamicreports). `customerSupplier` и `itemSupplier` предоставляют константный набор элементов для инициализации cписков `customers` и `items` соответственно.

Проще говоря: я беру определённого покупателя (Customer) и нахожу все товары, которые он заказал (хранятся в Map).

Поскольку знакомство с Java Stream API я начал недавно, я не совсем понимаю как собрать элементы из Map в List с помощью `Stream`. Нужно ли писать собственный `Collector`, или есть более простое решение? Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: xxxSupplier - это какие-то Optional-ы?

Comment: К сожалению я не знаю что такое Optional. Беглый поиск по гуглу наталкивает на мысль, что мои supplier-ы это не Optional. Это реализации функционального интерфейса Supplier, оба возвращают List из объектов определенного класса(Customer и Item соответственно)

Comment: У Вас происходит фильтрация всех MapEntry<Item> по ключу, который должен совпасть с ID вашего customer-a, правильно? Тогда эта операция выдаст максимум 1 entry, если ключ совпадает. И тогда вам собирать с пом коллекторов собственно нечего. Подозреваю, что Вы как-то не совсем правильно организовали хранение ваших заказов, кастомеров и item-ов. Или же в 2 словах (а лучше с пом кода!!!) опишите что должно происходить и что где хранится. UPD: кстати, в фильтре слово item сбивает с толку, т.к. вы работаете с entry, а класс Item не имеет никакого отношения к этому.

Comment: Что логически представляет строковый ключ вашей мапы?

Comment: В качестве ключа служит id покупателя(строка)

Comment: Ок, каждому покупателю соответствует один товар (ну, ладно, гипотетически такое возможно). И что полезного вы хотите получить из этого набора данных? Или все же хотели сделать Map<String, List<Item>> ???

Comment: В обновленном тексте 2 раза метод formOrders(). И потом... В конструкторе вы инициализируете orders с помощью метода formOrders(), в котором "изнутри" опять таки инициализируете orders новым ArrayList-ом, после чего наверное в этот лист хотите добавить нужные вам инвойсы, вернуть это все дело как результат метода... Т.е., что-то одно делайте - либо в методе (void) инициализируйте orders и добавляйте в него данные, либо в вашем варианте метода (и он правильный) создавайте локально ArrayList<Invoice> orders = new ..... и возвращайте его как результат метода!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если просто взять из мапы какие-то ключи (например, отфильтрованные по какому-то предикату), а значения собрать в листе, то что-то типа такого:

```
itemSupplier.get().entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals(customer.getId()))
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
);
```

Но непонятно что вы хотите дальше делать с инвойсом и зачем создавался лист orders...

Comment: Я самостоятельно дошел до решения полностью идентичного вашему, но появилась новая проблема. У каждого покупателя может быть несколько заказаных товаров, но такая фильтрация предоставляет только 1 товар(в список покупок попадает только **один вместо нескольких** необходимых товаров)

Comment: вот и я о том же писал выше в комментариях. Опишите структуру хранения данных для вашей системы. Как я понимаю, должен быть лист заказчиков, каждый из которых хранит лист заказов, каждый из которых хранит лист товаров. У вас, очевидно, не так. А как???

Comment: Если `itemSupplier` будет возвращать `Map<String, List<Item>>` вместо `Map<String, Item>`, то как правильно вытащить нужный мне лист из `Map`? Аналогичный вариант фильтрации выдает ошибку, суть которой мне не очень ясна: **incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: org.hillel_elem.homework_5.Item
    lower bounds: java.util.List<org.hillel_elem.homework_5.Item>**

Comment: Тогда не нужны никакие танцы. Просто из itemSupplier вызываем get(customerId) и получаем необходимый лист.

Comment: invoice.setItems(items.get(customer.getId())); - Ваш лист - это value, которое соответствует ключу, а ключ в данном случае - тот же (customer.getId())

Comment: cпасибо большое, разобрался